# Update value in Info.plist of other application

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nstask

**Problem:** I have an installer app which downloads an application in "/Applications/". I want to change some value in Info.plist of newly downloaded application when installer finishes.

**Possible solution:** We can use plistbuddy and `NSTask()` to run a script. But I do not know how to execute a command of terminal using `NSTask()` or how can I save script file in project and run that script when required.

**Example terminal command:** Running this command in terminal can change value in Info.plist of the downloaded app. How can I use this in my installer application.

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :SomeValue 'ToNewValue'" /Applications/DownloadedApp.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

Comment: That will break the code signature.  Game over.

Comment: I am not signing the application as it will not go to App Store.

Comment: That's fine then.  Don't use `plistbuddy`; instead read the `.plist` file into an `NSMutableDictionary`, change the value and then write it out again.  Much quicker and more reliable.

Comment: I say defaults as a terminal app.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, Will test it that way. @trojanfoe.

Comment: I know we can use defualts but I am looking for solution using programmatically. @ElTomato